# How did the Kraken die?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

The kraken is found lying dead on the beach in *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*. How did it end up dead?

One of my friends suggested it might have been the horrible tasting Capn. Jack Sparrow, but I disagreed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They discuss this in the movie, [Lord Cutler Beckett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutler_Beckett) says something along the lines of having ordered [Davy Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Jones_%28Pirates_of_the_Caribbean%29) to kill his ["pet"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraken_%28Pirates_of_the_Caribbean%29).

From the Kraken wikipedia:

> ...but it has been killed by Davy Jones under Lord Beckett's command. Davy Jones kills the Kraken by commanding it to beach itself on the island

Comment: Aaah... of course! So *that's* what Beckett is talking about! I was wondering what he meant by "pet'...